# zxing barcode not displaying any text

Tags: barcode, zxing

I made Barcode generator using ZXing Library but when barcode generate then it wont display text below barcode like

```
try {

    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "ABC-abc-1234");

    BitMatrix bitMatrix = new Code128Writer().encode("ABC-abc-1234", BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 350, 150, hints);

    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    // All are 0, or black, by default
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late to help you but I went through the same problem and was able to solve the following in a C#

```
var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    Options = new EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = 160,
        Width = 300,
        Margin = 0,
        PureBarcode = false
    },
    Renderer = new BitmapRenderer()
    {
        TextFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 15)
    }
};

var bitmap = barcodeWriter.Write("your content");
bitmap.Save(@"C:\\FULL\PATH\FILE.JPG");
```